# ERROR Async loop died! org.zeromq

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04, zeromq, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm new to ubuntu and storm , i need to solve this problem

```
[ERROR] Async loop died!
org.zeromq.ZMQException: Address already in use(0x62)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.bind(Native Method)
```

it appeared in worker log file due to `supervisor still hasn't start` and by searching found someone wrote that is due to

```
ephemeral port range was messed
up on the machines
```

tried to increase `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 1024 65000`

but not working

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to already used ports in your system. A port can only be used by a single application. Using `lsof -i` you can check what application are using which ports. You should spot an conflicting port number. Either terminate this application of change the configuration of Zookeeper or Storm to use a different port.

Comment: ok wrote only lsof -i and got alot of processes on firefox , can it be the problem ? i mean the port i used 6703 for supervisor should i write it after lsof -i 6703 ? or lsof -i

Comment: OK how can I change configuration of zookeeper I'm using 2181 clientport and for supervisor 6703

Comment: Look into `log/zoo.cfg` in your ZK directory to change the client port. For change the Storm configuration, modify `conf/storm.yaml` in you Storm directory.

Comment: i see that files but ports instead of 2181 ?? i searched for this error and found someone talked about ephemeral ports are messed up do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. `zoo.cfg` should contain a line `clientPort=2181`. Never heard of ephemeral ports -- no idea what this should be.

Comment: i mean what is alternative port except 2181? do you use storm under ubuntu as standalone operating system i mean do you use vmware or virtualbox

Comment: You can choose any free port you like. I run Storm in an Ubuntu cluster -- no virtual machines.

Comment: mm i'm using ubuntu via vmware could it be a problem with ports ? i changed port and problem still

Comment: I have only limited experience with vmware... No idea. Sorry.

Comment: no problem , i checked process in the port and got java -server -Djava.net.perfe , does it for topology i submitted ? should i close any browser during submitting topology or not ?